# Vertex Shader Creating

Tags: shader, directx-11, direct3d, vertex

I am learning D3D and currently i am at shaders. I wrote the code and built it - succeed but when debug i get this error:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cupIS.jpg)

Here is the line where debugger breake:

```
dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
```

And here is the whole function:

```
void InitPipeline()
{
    // load and compile the two shaders
    ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

    // set the shader objects
    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}
```

Comment: As you are new to Direct3D, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** You are not checking any of the HRESULT values for failure. For any COM API usage, including Direct3D, this is an essential coding step. Most likely you are getting a failure in the compile statements, so VS is coming back null.

You can use the `FAILED` and `SUCCEEDED` macros directly to do the error handling, or the [DX::ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) helper used in modern C++ samples.

```
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "VShader", "vs_4_0",
    0, 0, nullptr, &VS, nullptr, nullptr)))
    // error
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "PShader", "ps_4_0",
    0, 0, nullptr, &PS, nullptr, nullptr)))
    // error
```

> You should also use `nullptr` with VS 2010 or later instead of 0 when passing NULL pointer parameters to help keep them straight with the various DWORD parameters you are using 0 for.

**(2)** For the COM API, you should also consider using a smart-pointer like [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr)  rather than raw pointers which will automatically handle calling `Release` when the variable goes out of scope.

```
#include <wrl/client.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<ID3D10Blob> VS, PS;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "VShader",
    "vs_4_0", 0, 0, nullptr, &VS, nullptr, nullptr));
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "PShader",
    "ps_4_0", 0, 0, nullptr, &PS, nullptr, nullptr));

DX::ThrowIfFailed(dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(),
    nullptr, &pVS)(;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(),
    nullptr, &pPS));
```

In your code above, you are never calling `Release` on `VS` or `PS` so would end up leaking that memory.

**(3)** All versions of D3DX including D3DX11 are deprecated, as is the DirectX SDK itself (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)). With VS 2012 or later, you already have the Windows 8.x SDK which has Direct3D 11 headers and the HLSL compiler. Instead of using `D3DX11CompileFromFile` which is just a wrapper function, call `D3DCompileFromFile` directly (see [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)).

```
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> VS, PS;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "VShader",
    "vs_4_0", 0, 0, &VS, nullptr));
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "PShader",
    "ps_4_0", 0, 0, &PS, nullptr));

DX::ThrowIfFailed(dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(),
    nullptr, &pVS)(;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(),
    nullptr, &pPS));
```

**UPDATE**: If you need more detail on the error you are getting back from `D3DCompileFromFile` you should provide a `ID3DBlob` for the errors:

```
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> VS, Errors;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", nullptr, nullptr, "VShader",
    "vs_4_0", 0, 0, &VS, &Errors));
if ( Errors )
{
    OutputDebugStringA( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( Errors->GetBufferPointer() ) );
}
```

Comment: I still do not get it. When i need to check for that HRESULT, after compile from file or when i create vertex shader?

Also i used NULL insted of 0 but i changed it because i was trying something and it was easier for me to track.

Else i have Realise but in other funcion (void function where i release everything i on one place.

Comment: Forgot about this question. I got it is stupid and i figured it out myself when i red the code you send me and i got it that it is failing to compile from file but how can i figure it out why is it doing it?

Comment: See the UPDATE to the answer above.