# Creating Vertex Shader

Tags: directx-11, direct3d, vertex-shader

I have problem when creating vertex shader, it popup this error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF4Bt.jpg)

After some time I realized that **D3DX11CompileFromFile** is not working and it does not compile.

Here is my code:

```
    void InitPipeline()
{
    // load and compile the two shaders
    ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", NULL, NULL, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("Shaders.shader", NULL, NULL, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), 0, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), 0, &pPS);

    // set the shader objects
    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}
```

Please help if you can, I am new to D3D

Comment: This exact question has been answered before. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340965/vertex-shader-creating/34345219#34345219)

Comment: Yap and someone answerd but then i answer again and had no replay for few days so i asked again...